# Unknown rejection when trying to store a cookie

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to store an Object in a cookie, so it can be stored (put) in one web page and be used (get) in another.
I'm using `angular#1.5.8`, and `angular-cookies#1.5.8`.

In the JS includes I have both:

```
<script src="~/lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
```

In the module I have the `"ngCookies"` dependency, with no further configuration.
In the service (factory), I have the `"$cookies"` dependency as-well.
When I use the `$cookie`, e.g.

```
$cookies.put('aForm', 'kuku');
```

I get this rejection from the developer's tab in Chrome:

```
angular.js:14832 Possibly unhandled rejection: {}(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14832(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10848g @ angular.js:16626$eval @ angular.js:17913$digest @ angular.js:17645$apply @ angular.js:17929l @ angular.js:11945N.onload @ angular.js:12516
```

Any help?

Comment: not possible. a cookie can only store TEXT. basically a `key=value` string. The only way you could store an object is by serializing it and storing the string you get from serialization.

Comment: @MarcB , sorry, but can you explain a little bit more?
In the example shown above, I try to store a string and it is still not working.
As I see cookies, it meant to store cross-page info, using key->value dictionary.
But storing key=value is kind of odd... because, why cookies then if the key known by the 2 participants, is also the value... Thanks